# Postgis and python parameterised queries

Tags: postgresql, osm2pgsql, pgsql2shp

I have a python script that i am trying to run in order to dump a postgres table and I noticed there is a pgsql2shp command in bash to perform this easily but I would like to incoperate the same command in a python script and also use parameter substitution. I thought the following would work but it hasn't yielded any result.  What is the equivalent of the this command in python

```
(pgsql2shp -f %s.shp -h localhost -p 5432 testdb "%s_%s")%(table,table,test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pythons [Subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to execute shell commands.

```
command = 'pgsql2shp -f %s.shp -h localhost -p 5432 testdb \"%s_%s\" ' % (table,table,test)
sp.call(command.split())
```